# How to specify a gcc path in pip command?

Tags: gcc, pip, g++, cupy

I am trying to install cupy 5.0.0. cupy5.0.0 needs gcc version not more than 7. My deafault gcc is gcc-9. I cannot use conda environment. Also i dont have sudo permission to change /usr/bin/gcc to point to gcc-7. Is there any way to pass gcc path to pip command?

Comment: `PATH=/usr/loca/bin:$PATH pip install …` `/usr/loca/bin` is just an example; it must be a directory where your alternative `gcc` resides.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `CXX`, `CC` and `LD` environment variables to specify executable names or full paths to C++ and C compilers, and the linker.

Specify the variables only for one command:

```
CXX=g++-7 CC=gcc-7 LD=g++-7 pip install ...
```

Alternatively:

```
export CXX=g++-7 
export CC=gcc-7
export LD=g++-7 
pip install ...
```

You can also pass extra compiler and linker options in `CXXFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS`. Preprocessor options (e.g. include directories) go in `CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is it possible to specify cuda_host_compiler also for nvcc? In the process of installation somewhere it is using the cuda_host_compiler as the default one.

Comment: @BhaswatiSaha You can use this method to pass any environment variables to `pip`, but you need to find out which environment variable controls that.