# How do you install a PIP package using a specific GCC compiler version?

Tags: c++, gcc, installation, pip, anaconda

I've been trying to install the package mmcv-full in Python 3.10 using PIP while inside an anaconda environment, however I keep getting this error when doing so:

```
Emitting ninja build file /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build.ninja...
      Compiling objects...
      Using envvar MAX_JOBS (4) as the number of workers...
      [1/128] c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.o.d -pthread -B /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include -fPIC -DMMCV_WITH_CUDA -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common/cuda -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include/python3.10 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.o -std=c++14 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
      FAILED: /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.o
      c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.o.d -pthread -B /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/compiler_compat -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include -fPIC -O2 -isystem /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include -fPIC -DMMCV_WITH_CUDA -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common -I/tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common/cuda -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/TH -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/THC -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/include/python3.10 -c -c /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.cpp -o /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.o -std=c++14 -DTORCH_API_INCLUDE_EXTENSION_H '-DPYBIND11_COMPILER_TYPE="_gcc"' '-DPYBIND11_STDLIB="_libstdcpp"' '-DPYBIND11_BUILD_ABI="_cxxabi1011"' -DTORCH_EXTENSION_NAME=_ext -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
      In file included from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.cpp:5:
      /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:4:2: error: #error C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use ATen.
       #error C++17 or later compatible compiler is required to use ATen.
        ^~~~~
      In file included from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/Generator.h:12,
                       from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/CPUGeneratorImpl.h:3,
                       from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:3,
                       from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:7,
                       from /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/common/pytorch_cpp_helper.hpp:3,
                       from /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full_42af0b6427974452b4a43d94b764ae55/mmcv/ops/csrc/pytorch/active_rotated_filter.cpp:5:
      /home/vargog/anaconda3/envs/Donkey3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/include/c10/util/C++17.h:27:2: error: #error You need C++17 to compile PyTorch
       #error You need C++17 to compile PyTorch
```

The command I've been running to install is `pip3 install mmcv-full`.

Is there a way to run this command with my C++ version set to C++17 instead of the C++14 that pip is grabbing for some reason?  Perhaps an argument of some kind.

I've tried the methods described in the post here : [How to specify a gcc path in pip command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017279/how-to-specify-a-gcc-path-in-pip-command) , however these didn't seem to work.  I also attempted to add an argument to specify the compiler version before the pip command, `std=c++17 pip3 install mmcv-full`, though this didn't work either.

Thanks

Comment: The std=c++17 needs to be on the `c++ -MMD -MF /tmp/pip-install-uk4j3r7w/mmcv-full...` command line. How you get it there, danged if I know. Should have been specified in ninja build script. Was that script generated in an earlier stage?

Answer (score 0):

if you use cuda (nvcc), you can set this [environment variable](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmcv/blob/main/setup.py#L159) to `-std=c++17` before running `pip install mmcv-full`
else you will have to compile it from [source](https://mmcv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started/build.html).